# Textarea to filtred array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to take the value of textarea, split it into different properties.

Data in textfield(This is an example, there is alot more spaces in the real input):

```
    name       lastname        age             fruit
    john                doe             22             apple
eric                jonsson             23             apple
```

This Is my code right now:

```
        var textareadataData = $('#textareaID').val().split('\n');
```

Result:

```
"    name       lastname        age             fruit"
"    john                doe             22             apple"
"eric                jonsson             23             apple"
```

I want the result to be:

```
"name","lastname","age","fruit"
"john","doe","22";"apple"
"eric", "jonsson","23","apple"
```

I've tried to search around but didn't find the answer.

Best Regards Wiak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whitespace splitting after the one for new line.

The code below adds up your new-line-split with the operations:

1. Filter out empty lines
2. Split each line on multiple spaces (not to split `green apple` as you said in the comment)
3. Gets rid of the empty/whitespace elements of the nested arrays

```js
// This is your code
var textareaData = $('#textareaID').val().split('\n');

// This is the extra code you can add (split whitespaces and filter out resulting ones)
var words = textareaData
  .filter(x => x.length !== 0)
  .map(x => x.split(/(\s\s+)/))
  .map(x => x.filter(el => el.trim()));

console.log(words)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textareaID">
    name       lastname        age             fruit
    john                doe             22       green apple
eric                jonsson             23             apple
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hmm, it works, almost. It counts the white spaces as property aswell. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Added a working example with the additional feedback you've supplied.

Comment: In my arrays, I got some arrays in it that have spaces but is filtered as their own array example "green apple", and the result is "green", "apple", but I want "green apple"... Are you able to help here? (It works like a charm except that error).

Comment: Then, the regex can be modified to match more than one space by converting `\s+` to `\s\s+`. Added it with an example `green apple`, check it out.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
var string = $('#textareaID').val().replace(/\s+/g,' ')
```

The regex will replace all space by one space

then you can use split as usual

```
string.split(" ");
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: $(...).val(...) is not a function

Comment: sorry i forget the "replace function"

Comment: or simply `.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave one space betwwen words with a regular expression:

```
var textData = textareadataData.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Then split it again with the spaces:

```
var textDataArray = textData.split(" ");
```

And there you have it.
You can do it in just one line but I did it in two just to explain it.

Comment: Im getting the following error: $(...).val(...) is not a function  
@Maxime posted the same

Comment: Sure, if you write ´$('#textareaID').val()(/\s+/g,' ')´ you will get that error, but you need to write it like this: $('#textareaID').val().replace(/\s+/g," ").split(" ")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$('#textareaID').val().split('\n').map(val => val.trim().replace(/[ ]+/g, " ").split(" "));
```

To explain the code:

`$('#textareaID').val().split('\n')` is your code

`.map()` iterates over all lines

`val.trim()` removes outer whitespaces

`replace(/[ ]+/g, " ")` removes all duplicated whitespaces

`split(" ")` splits everything

Comment: Can you provide a demo JSfiddle?